# Scan error on column index 1: unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type <nil> into type *string

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a column in postgres which is blank initially

```
var dtime sql.NullString

err = rows.Scan(&dtime)

if dtime.Valid {
    dtimeString = dtime.String
} else {
    dtime = sql.NullString{}
}
```

rows are are a result set of a sql query from my table.

```
select dtime from mytable;  // returns 5 rows.
```

But I keep getting

```
Scan error on column index 1: unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type <nil> into type *string.
```

I have tried whats given here - https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString

Comment: What does `dtime = dtime` even mean? Show the actual code please.

Comment: editted the question.

Comment: How do you define row?

Comment: Define a row? You mean columns in a row?

Comment: Are you actually checking that error? It looks like it should work.. What does all of the surrounding code look like?